# Microsoft AD GUID Mismatch

Tags: active-directory, guid

This has probably been answered before, but I can't find anything to help for the life of me.  We have different systems, and some of the older ones have a different AD guids for the same person when compared to  newer systems.  The guids look similar, but are different.  This is causing a big problem in a new app I am doing that is reading a SQL database form and older and newer app.  Here is an example, and older one is this: `147e2a1e-579e-a143-88b9-d3a8ee00e609` and a newer one is this `1e2a7e14-9e57-43a1-88b9-d3a8ee00e609`. If I read AD with .NET it gives me the "newer" guid.  What is the cause of this, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this problem before.  It is caused by the way different tools interpret the bits in AD differently.  I bet you can convert one to the other by swapping things around.  You just need to figure out the algorithm.  I wrote some code that fixed something similar in one instance, may not be exactly what will fix yours, but should get you on the right path.

```
Private Shared Function SymmetricConversion(source As Guid) As Guid

    Dim sourceStr = source.ToString()
    Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    'group 1
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(6, 2))
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(4, 2))
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(2, 2))
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(0, 2))

    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(8, 1))

    'group 2
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(11, 2))
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(9, 2))

    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(13, 1))

    'group 3
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(16, 2))
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(14, 2))

    'groups 4 and 5
    sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(18, sourceStr.Length - 18))

    Dim resultStr = sb.ToString()
    Dim result = New Guid(resultStr)
    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: Awesome!  It looks like your code will actually fix my problem.  That is interesting that the same code converts both ways.